# Should I log error where I throw it or where I catch it?

Tags: php

Should I log error where I throw it like this :

```
try {
    addOne();
} catch (Exception $e) {

}

function addOne($number) {
    if (empty($number)) {
        Log::instance()->add(Log::ERROR, $e->getMessage());
        throw Exception('The incoming number is empty');
    }
    return $number+1;
}
```

or where I catch it like this?

```
try {
    addOne();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Log::instance()->add(Log::ERROR, $e->getMessage());
}

function addOne($number) {
    if (empty($number)) {
    throw Exception('The incoming number is empty');
    }
    return $number+1;
}
```

Comment: I would say you should throw the error/exception inside the method itself with a descriptive message, and log the error inside the catch block.

Comment: I always log in `catch` block. `catch` block is for dealing with exceptions and logging is one form of that. But question is opinion-based.

Comment: Both are the bad (not wrong) ways to log and throw the exceptions. If please unhold the question for a minutes so that I can post revised code.

Comment: For PHP we should follow the ZEND standards, log error in the main function body and throw exceptions (custom/original) in catch block.

Comment: @SatyamSaxena If you throw exception in catch block where are you going to catch them?

Comment: @Leri, like that:

<?php

try {
    addOne();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    throw Exception('The incoming number is empty');
}

function addOne($number) {
    if (empty($number)) {
        Log::instance()->add(Log::ERROR, $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $number+1;
}
?>

Comment: @SatyamSaxena Uhm, you know how exceptions are used, don't you?

Comment: @Leri: Yes, of course :-). I have been coding in ZEND for last 3 years and in PHP for more than 7 years. Also I alwyas use automatic build to check my coding standards.

Comment: @SatyamSaxena, I don't understand your piece of code either :). What are you trying to catch if the method `addOne` doesn't throw anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As days Rami, throwing the error/exception inside the method itself with a descriptive message, and logging the error inside the catch block is a good solution. It will allow you to have only one logging instruction for logging different kind of exception wich can occur in your code. Logging when you throw the exception will multiply logging messages and increase your code size without any added-value, furthermore if you use the function in several catch block, you won't be able to trace in which one it has failed.

Answer (score -1):

You should log an error when it's been caught (in the catch), otherwise your method will be called even when their is a fail and no error will be logged, unless you want to log that it has succeed, then you either place where it is now or use a finally to log it.