# should the error be logged when we are intentionally raising exception

Tags: python, exception, logging

I have made a custom exception, so my question is should I log the error before it is being raised.

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass


if not someList:
    # do I need to log here
    logger.error("something went wrong")
    raise MyException("Something wrong.")
```

Comment: It depends your intention, there is no good absolute response. Are you coding exception handling ? If yes you may want to log at the handler level that you handle the exception, if not, the exception trace will contains a reference to the point the exception were raised to allow you to track the failure. Anyway, in all case take care of furnishing a good and complete description of what went wrong in the exception message.

Comment: but I am still awaiting a perfect answer some more explanation perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly look into this opinion based question on *[where to log errors - where i throw or where i catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355494/should-i-log-error-where-i-throw-it-or-where-i-catch-it)*. It is applicable to exception/error handling in any language.

In general, the idea is to log the error only once -

- to avoid more IO operations,
- will not increase your code size without any additional value.
- tracing gets difficult (with just the error message without stack trace) if you log it at the source of error - it gets quite hard to find the caller who received the exception.

In this scenario, it depends whether you catch the exception somewhere or it is thrown straight.

You can see that the above question was closed with a note that it is opinion based. So it is more of your opinion and your use case, than a strict convention.